# Fourth moment of a itos integral

Tags: brownian-motion, itos-lemma, expected-value

$I(t)=\int_0^t \sqrt sdW_s$

What is $E(I(t)^4)$

Answer (score 3):

$I(t)=\int_0^t \sqrt tdW_s=\sqrt t \int_0^t dW_s  =\sqrt t W_t $
and then
$$E(I(t)^4)=E(t^2 W_t^4)=t^2 \cdot 3t^2=3t^4$$
using the [4th moment of the $N(0,\sigma^2=t)$ distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)).

Comment: But it is "s" in the integral and not t. You can not take it outside ...maybe it was edited after your answer

Comment: Yes the question was changed

Comment: Why can't you take t outside? I'm looking over this problem for review and this part didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Jessie you can, but I'm answering the original question, not the edited question.

Comment: Many thanks! Would you be able to provide a hint on how t^2 and 3t^2 were derived? I believe Itô's isometry needs to be applied here but unsure how.

Answer (score 2):

Note that because the integrand is deterministic this Itô integral is normally distributed with parameters (cf. Itô isometry)
$$ I_t := \int_0^t \sqrt{s} dW_s \sim N(0, t^2/2) $$
Now you can just use the results that apply for the moments of a Gaussian variable.